# Why does the code stop executing after this function call?

Tags: python

Here's the primary codeblock.

```
variables = ['V1','V2','V3',...]
caseList = ['C1','C2','C3',...]
exp = {}
conv = {}
result = {}

for case in caseList:
    if case != "Processed":
        load_case(case, dirPath, fileTyp)
        import_rawData(fileTyp)
        convert_units()
        display('Hello')
        merge_Data(case)
        display('Hello')
```

Here's the output of that codeblock. Nothing executes after the `merge_Data()` function call.

```
'Case loaded'
'Raw data imported'
'Units converted'
'Hello'
'Data filtered'
'Data merged'
```

Here is the code for the `merge_Data`, and associated `filter_expData` functions:

```
def merge_Data(case):
    fexpData = filter_expData(case)

    for var in variables:
        exists = fexpData.get(var,"")

        if len(exists) > 0:
            temp = conv[var]
            temp[var,temp[var].columns[1].replace('Simulation','Experiment')] = pd.Series(fexpData[var].tolist())
            temp[var,'Absolute Error'] = abs(temp[var,temp[var].columns[1]] - temp[var,temp[var].columns[2]])
            temp[var,'Percentage Error'] = temp[var,temp[var].columns[3]] / temp[var,temp[var].columns[2]] * 100

            result[var] = temp

        else:
            result[var] = conv[var]

    display('Data merged')

def filter_expData(case):
    var = next(iter(conv))

    timeList = pd.Series(conv[var].iloc[:,conv[var].columns.get_level_values(1)=="Time (min)"].iloc[:,0].round(3))

    filtExp = exp[case][exp[case]['Time (min)'].round(3).isin(timeList)]

    display('Data filtered')
    return filtExp
```

Can you help me understand why code isn't executing after the `merge_Data()` function call?

Comment: Where did you declare `variables`?

Comment: `variables` is just a list, globally declared.

Comment: Connect a debugger to see what happens. Or wrap merge_data around a try...except clause to catch the exception.